# Удалить все из строки php

Tags: php, форматирование

Всем привет, вот есть например вот такая строка vk.com/id11111, как удалять все символы за исключением id11111? Если строка может изменяться на такую m.vk.com/id11111 или с добавлением протокола?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$url = "https://m.vk.com/id111";
$url = explode("/", $url);
$id = $url[count($url)-1];
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
$url='http://vk.com/id11111';
echo substr(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH),1);
```

ну и вариация кода Андрея Колесова

```
$url='http://vk.com/id11111';
echo end(explode('/', $url));
```